# Add resource assignment work by day

Tags: c#, csom, project-server, project-online

For a few days I'm trying to write the assignment progress for a specific task for a specific date. For example: I'm able to set the overall progress of the task but not the actual work that resource did at a given date. We are able to do that using Project Pro on the Task Usage view, but we need to automate some actions based on a file generated by another system and that's why i'm working in this solution but I could not find any object that would allow me to save the actual work value for a date. I'm using the CSOM library and Project Online.

This problem is driving me crazy! Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In case I wasn't clear enough, I basically need to get and set data from the resource assignments BY DAY, as we can view and set through the TASK USAGE screen on Project PRO, but I need to do it using CSOM and Project Online.
Here's the view I'm talking about:
[image: Project Pro Task Usage view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, we managed to find a way out...
Here's how we did it:

```
    private void SaveAssignmentData(Guid id, DateTime start, DateTime finish, Config config)
    {  

        //start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);
        //finish = start.AddHours(10); //from 8am to 6pm

        var ctx = new Connection().ProjectOnline(config.SpOnlineSite, config.SpOnlineUsuario, config.SpOnlineSenha); //simple method to get the current context

        var resources = ctx.EnterpriseResources;
        ctx.Load(resources);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        var resource = ctx.EnterpriseResources.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email == "user@domain.com");
        if (resource == null) throw new Exception("Resource not found.");
        ctx.Load(resource, p => p.Assignments);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var timePhase = resource.Assignments.GetTimePhase(start, finish);
        ctx.Load(timePhase, p => p.Assignments);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var statusAssignment = timePhase.Assignments.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        if (statusAssignment != null)
        {
            statusAssignment.ActualWork = "6h";
            statusAssignment.SubmitStatusUpdates("through csom");
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```